# Nested Complex Types in Function Import Mapping

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have two stored procedures that return a slightly different set of columns. I have a separate ComplexType defined to manage each of the result types.

The two types do however share a lot of similar columns - say for example, the first 10 columns are the same and then the next 4 or 5 vary.

Is it possible to create a third ComplexType - say BaseType and have it as a property of the the other two types. Making their definition much simpler.

The IDE will allow me to set this up, however i cannot get it to function correctly at runtime.

I kind of feel that it should be possible as the IDE allows me to set this up.

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that although the IDE will allow you to set up this nesting of complex types it is deemed to be illegal. In order to resolve this i simply had to create flat complex type definitions and accept there is some basic field duplication